Showing cos$(x^2)$ is analytic
In the textbook that I am using I am given the following definition and theorem:
Definition: A function $f$ whose Taylor series converges to $f$ in a neighborhood of $c$ is said to be analytic at $c$.
Theorem: Let $f$ be infinitely differentiable in a neighborhood $I$ of $c$. Suppose $x \in I$ and there exists $M>0$ such that $ |f^{(m)}(t)| \leq M$ for all $m \in \Bbb{N}$ and $t \in [c,x]$ (or $[x,c] \text{ if } x<c).$ Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} R_n(x)=0$. Thus, $f$ is analytic at $c$.
Then the question I am having trouble with is showing that cos$(x^2)$ is analytic at $x=0$. What I am attempting to do is to use the formula for $R_n(x)$. Which is $\displaystyle R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}$.
But trying to find a bound for all the derivatives of cos$(x^2)$ is giving me a difficult time because of having to apply the chain rule. Is there a simple technique that I am missing given this definition and theorem?

Did you get a bound for $n=0$? For $n=1$? For $n=2$? If you got that far, did you conjecture a pattern?

@LeeMosher For $n=0$ bound would be $2$, for $n=1$ I have a bound of $6$ and at least for the inequalities that I am creating my bounds just keep increasing. Inspecting the graphs of the derivatives also doesn't provide insight onto a bound that would work for all derivatives. So I'm not sure what to apply here.

Possible hint: $$\cos(x^2) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} x^{4k}$$

HINTS: Use the Taylor polynomial $P_{n,g}$ (at $0$) of degree $n$ with remainder for $g(x)=\cos x$ to show that
for $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$, the Taylor polynomial $P_{2n,f}$ of degree $2n$ is given by $P_{2n,f}(x) = P_{n,g}(x^2)$.
Use the remainder estimate for $g$ to give a remainder estimate for $f$. Now deduce that $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb R$.

Okay this is something that I had thought about doing but I thought it did not work since let's say $g(x)=P_{n,g}(x)+R_{n,g}(x)$ does this imply that $g(x^2)=P_{n,g}(x^2)+R_{n,g}(x^2)$ and that I do not have to consider anything new about the term $g^{(n+1)}(z)$ in the remainder term?

Actutally considering my previous comment I guess $g^{(n+1)}(z)$ is a constant so it makes sense.

It’s not constant, but you have easy bounds!
